# Повторение записи в ячейке (подсказка) DataGrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы текст, раннее введенный в ячейку DataGrid, повторялся после следующего ввода в другую ячейку (примерно как в Excel, см. анимацию)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы пробовали? Что-то подобное есть в штатном поведении ComboBox, можно попробовать это использовать

Comment: У меня есть представление, что чтение можно сделать из XML файла, т.е. за ранее сохраненные в нем данные (в XML). Данные выводятся при загрузке программы в таблицу DataGrid, где-то вокруг до около представление минимальное есть, по моему мнению вроде как XMLReader но это пока что только вилами по воде писано. Я могу предоставить код с сохраняемыми данными в XML если что.

Comment: При чем тут вообще XML?

Comment: Я имел ввиду как один из вариантов, так как я на начальной стадии изучееия, то большего мне пока не понять.

Comment: Вам надо сделать автодополнение текста по какой-то коллекции строк, а откуда эта коллекция строк берется — это уже третий вопрос.

Comment: Понял спасибо, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобное поведение есть в штатном `ComboBox` (в режиме `IsEditable="True"`), можно этим воспользоваться. Я покопался в шаблоне и выбросил всё лишнее, получается вот что:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" Padding="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}">
    <ComboBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                     VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Template>
</ComboBox>
```

В `ItemsSource` привязываете коллекцию строк из которых надо автодополнять, результат ввода можно забирать из свойства `Text`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Итак, применить этот трюк с `ComboBox` совместно с `DataGrid` мне до конца не удалось (с другой стороны, пихать `ComboBox` внутрь шаблона `TextBox` может быть не слишком уж и рационально), поэтому предлагаю другое решение — написать самостоятельно функционал автодополнения (на самом деле он довольно прост в написании) или взять готовый.

Я взял по одной из первых ссылок в google этот пакет: [WPFTextBoxAutoComplete](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFTextBoxAutoComplete/) ([здесь](https://github.com/Nimgoble/WPFTextBoxAutoComplete/) можно посмотреть как его использовать).

Пишем VM-часть. Мы должны подготовить строки для автодополнения. Пусть у меня такая простая сущность:

```
class ItemVm : Vm
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => Set(ref name, value);
    }
}
```

А в главной VM коллекция этих сущностей:

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemVm> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemVm>();
```

Тогда я могу в главной VM выставить такое свойство:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Strings => Items.Select(i => i.Name).Distinct().OrderBy(s => s);
```

Остается только как-то оповещать при изменениях строк, это не сильно сложно:

```
public MainVm()
{
    Items.CollectionChanged += OnItemsCollectionChanged;
}

private void OnItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            foreach (ItemVm item in e.NewItems)
                item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            foreach (ItemVm item in e.OldItems)
                item.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
            break;
        // Остальные Action
    }
    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Strings));
}

private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ItemVm.Name))
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Strings));
}
```

Готово. Теперь представление:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">

        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Ячейка во время редактирования превращается в TextBox без границ, переопределяем стиль для нее:

```
            <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="behaviors:AutoCompleteBehavior.AutoCompleteItemsSource"
                            Value="{Binding DataContext.Strings, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

где `xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:WPFTextBoxAutoComplete;assembly=WPFTextBoxAutoComplete"` — пространство имен, которое вам необходимо подключить

Пример почти работает, за исключением первого нажатия в ячейке — автодополнение срабатывает, но при этом слетает выделение, что ведет к неудобству использования, вы столкнетесь с этим независимо от того, будете ли писать свое автодополнение или возьмете готовое.

Я решил это следующим образом, добавим в стиль обработчик события `Loaded` (да, TextBox еще не загружен в том момент, когда он обработал первое нажатие! и при загрузке сбрасывает выделение):

```
                    <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="TextBox_Loaded"/>
```

В обработчике пишем:

```
    private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        if (textBox.IsSelectionActive)
            textBox.SelectionLength = textBox.Text.Length - textBox.SelectionStart;
    }
```

т.е. просто восстанавливаем выделение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, как только к программе доберусь, буду пробовать, ещё раз спасибо, в инете (в поисковиках) вообще по данному вопросу зацепиться не за что.

Comment: День добрый, у меня не получается заменить nameof, я думаю это вероятнее всего из того-что, у меня установлена версия Visual 2012, всё перепробовал вокруг да около, в точку попасть никак не могу. И PropertyChanged я так понимаю должен создать событие?

Comment: Ну, конечно, желательно использовать свежую версию языка. А вообще вместо `nameof(Strings)` можете использовать `"Strings"`, а вместо `nameof(ItemVm.Name)` — `"Name"`. Главное при переименовании свойства не забыть изменить и строчку, иначе она перестанет работать

Comment: Спасибо, понял.....

Comment: В общем нагородил я чего не поподя, так и не справился я с задачей.

Comment: Если есть у вас возможность, не поглядите мою галиматью..

Comment: Проблему нашёл......

Comment: Разобрались? Получилось запустить пример из этого ответа?

Comment: Да из Вашего ответа, чё то копал, копал и накопал.:))))

Comment: Здравствуйте, у меня вопрос в продолжении данной темы, по поводу IEnumerable в присутствии лямда выражений, или же мне лучше вопрос по новой теме задать(он связан в Visual 2012)?

Comment: Что за вопрос? Почему вы до сих пор не обновили студию?

Comment: Я пытаюсь, хотя бы более половины понять по 2012, я за вами не успею тогда никогда, вот один из вариантов как раз такой: как мне строку в IEnumerable<string> Strings => Items.Select(i => i.Name).Distinct().OrderBy(s => s); адаптировать под 2012 год, она у меня соответственно постоянно слетает, немного помучиться хотелось бы, ну а потом и 2017 перейти.

Comment: Что значит "слетает"? Как-то так пробовали переписать: `public IEnumerable<string> Strings { get { return Items.Select(i => i.Name).Distinct().OrderBy(s => s); } }` ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80434/discussion-between--and--nop).