# Фильтрация в Grid подобно Excel

Tags: wpf, .net

В Excel можно поставить фильтр и снизу появится кнопка, нажав на которую отобразятся все уникальные варианты в данной колонке, а затем нажав на галку можно выполнить фильтрацию и скрыть строки, которые не подходят по условию.

Как подобное можно сделать в WPF?

На ум приходит ручная работа с событиями. Однако, на сколько я знаю, такой подход не приветствуется в WPF.

Или в моем случае нужно пилить собственный контрол, который за кулисами хранит уникальные значения каждого столбца?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Повторение записи в ячейке (подсказка) DataGrid wpf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853373/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-datagrid-wpf)

Comment: @АндрейNOP не совсем то. По ссылке автокомплит на основании записей в предыдущей ячейках, а я про фильтр. Т.е в Excel можно сделать первую строку фильтрующей и в итоге в нижнем правом углу появится значок-кнопка, нажав на который можно выбрать какие-то значения и скрыть строки, которые удволитворяют данному условию.

Comment: Ну тогда ничего сложного — помещаете в шаблон заголовка столбца DataGrid ComboBox и при смене текущего значения в нем фильтруете строки. Реализация будет зависеть от того, на какой стороне (V или VM) вы решите фильтровать данные