# Живой поиск внутри ячейки DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, поиск, datagrid, combobox

всем привет. есть идеи, как реализовать живой поиск в DataGrid? Имеется в виду, нужно сделать чтобы когда нажимаешь по ячейке DataGrid и начинаешь ввод текста, выскакивает ComboBox с поиском вхождений с возможными вариантами.

**UPDATE**

Имелось в виду следующее:
У меня есть dataGrid, в нём, когда встаёшь на ячейку, нужно чтобы вылезало всплываюющее или выпадающее меню (всё равно) со списком возможных вариантов. Также, в ячейке должен присутствовать TextBox или его аналог.

Вот что мне удалось сделать:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Параметр">

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.VmParameters}" 
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedParameter}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="ParameterName" BorderThickness="0"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00a78e"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

В данном случае беда в том, что все ComboBox в столбце разом принимают значение из выбранного мной одного экземпляра.
Если можно сделать это через Popup, было бы здорово

Comment: В ячейке Datagrid же данные, и при нажать на ячейку, то будет редактироваться сама ячейка. Комбобокс - это вы выпадающий список так странно назвали? Вам нужно поле с фильтрацией и подсказками, расположенное над таблицей? Ваш вопрос мне непонятен, совсем.

Comment: @aepot наверно имелось ввиду как в экселе. Встаешь на ячейку, начинаешь вводить и предлагает уже ранее вставленные слова. Ну или как поиск в гугле

Comment: @ДмитрийСуворов это тогда уже не поиск получается, а автозаполнение ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338690/wpf-autocomplete-textbox-again), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294090/using-wpf-textbox-autocomplete-in-a-datagrid)).

Comment: Это не оно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/853555/218063 ?